# How to check whether a shell script is running in the server

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, command

I am running a shell script in server with command line arguments as follows.

```
./xyz.sh DD 10 20
```

I want to write some check code inside the script that it will detect if same script is running in the server. If the same is running then it won't run , otherwise it will run. N.B. the command line arguments may differ for different run of the same script.

Any help on this is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have various ways of checking if a program is running.

### Checking for a running program *with the same name*

```
pidof xyz
```

This will print the pids of every program named "`xyz`", and return with exit code `0` if a pid was found and `1` if not (so if you just want to know if the program is running, you just have to check the exit code of that command).

If you don't have `pidof`:

```
ps aux | grep xyz.sh | grep -v grep
```

And check if the output is empty or not.

### A more reliable solution

If you want something a bit more sophisticated (that will check if **this** script is running, and not just something with the same name), the solution is usually to create a pid file:

At the beginning of the script, check if the file `/var/run/xyz.pid` exists. If it exists, then the program is already running. If not, then **create it** and continue your normal execution. At the end of the normal execution of the script, remove the file.

You may write the pid of the script as you create the `xyz.pid` file. That way, if the user wants to stop the running script without killing it themselves, they can call the script again with an option like, for example, `--stop`. Then your script can read the `.pid` file and kill it properly (by sending a signal asking it to shut down gracefully for example).

This is the way a lot of services (some http servers for example) work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try implementing a lock file.
First create a file when the shell executes.
Before creating the file check if it exists. If it does then skip the process if not continue.

Comment: Hi DRTauli, I want a check inside the script it self.. So any sugestion on this?

Comment: use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828035/linux-command-to-check-if-a-shell-script-is-running-or-not) to get your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828035/linux-command-to-check-if-a-shell-script-is-running-or-not